# Can a Sinatra or Rack application find out if it is running with Apache or Thin?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rack

I am trying to do some silly automatic configuration of a Sinatra application which would allow to use it from different sub URI depending whether it is run with Apache and Passenger, or with Thin web server.

So my question is: is it possible to find out from inside a Sinatra application what web server runs it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't (as far as I know) see if it's running on Apache, but you can check if it's running on Passenger:

```
if defined?(PhusionPassenger)
  # We are running Passenger!
end
```

You should be able to do the same for Thin:

```
if defined?(Thin)
  # We are running Thin!
end
```

Comment: Thanks, this works! (I thought i tried to use `defined?`, but probably messed up something).